# Lua throwaway result

Tags: lua

I have a situation where I perform some operations on tables, call them T and V. I have set the metatable up correctly and everything works as expected. The issue is that I usually don't need the result of the calculation. So instead of writing

```
for i=1,5 do
    _=T+V
end
```

is there a way to just have

```
for i=1,5 do
    T+V
end
```

?

I am not using the Lua commandline so I cannot just write =T+V.

Comment: Why the hell would you perform a calculation where you don't need the result?

Comment: @DeadMG there's no reason why you couldn't say, overload the + operator on tables to modify the first table passed in with data from the second, although that doesn't seem very intuitive.

Comment: Really the place for a Lua-style member function, not an operator overload.

Comment: true, but the ability is there.

Comment: **1:** Lua grammar doesn't support what you're trying to do. **2:** Discarding the result of this expression makes it a NOP *unless* you made the addition operator modify one or both of its operands which would be *horrifically* bad programming.

Comment: @Mike: True that there's no reason you *couldn't*, but there are profound reasons you *shouldn't*, so much so that the question should be entirely moot.

Comment: I don't want to add fuel to the fire, but I am not asking for moral guidance here. I would rather prefer an answer to the question I asked.

Comment: @JohnSmith yeah, i'm pretty sure the answer here is that it is not possible to do what you're asking based on Lua's syntax. the best you could do would be to create some member function on T's type called add() that you pass a V to.

Comment: @John: **1:** The question was answered. You can confirm the answer via the language manual; [see the `stat ::=` clause](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#8) which shows what a legal statement in the language is. **2:** Morality has nothing to do with it; abuse of operator overloading to defy programmer expectations (like defining `+` to do subtraction, or to modify it's operands), its just bad programming (unless your goal is to be featured on [Daily WTF](http://us.thedailywtf.com/Comments/Yet-Another-Operator-Overloading-Abuse.aspx).

Answer (score 6):

Make a function that does nothing and pass it to it:

```
function NOP() end

for i=1,5 do
    NOP(T+V)
end
```

This additionally serves to document your intentions, and that the side-effect is what you're after.

Comment: pretty slick, so simple i can't believe i didn't think of it!

Comment: @MikeCorcoran I thought of it, but it seemed wasteful to add the overhead of a function call for no reason (`_=0` is around twice as fast as `NOP(0)`). In reality, we're talking about fractions of a microsecond in overhead so going with whatever reads best makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at [syntax of Lua in extended BNF](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#8) I don't see an way to construct an expression (exp) without a equal sign or something else.

There are only 4 cases where an expression (exp) can be used:

- Assigning a value e.g. `p = exp`
- As condition e.g. `while exp then`
- In a function call i.e. `f(exp)`
- for indexing i.e. `t[exp]`

Comment: indexing still needs assignment

Comment: @daurnimator not necessarily e.g. f(t[exp]) or if t[exp] then.

Comment: sure. but my point is it needs something else from this list to work.